# Calculating yearly performance statistics when looping over lists in R

Tags: r, list

Say I have 10 models I am running at two sites. Site 1 has daily data for three years, site two for four years. To run statistics on model performance, I loop over models and sites as such:

```
require(hydroGOF)
df <- NULL
model <- list()


dateO <- list(seq(as.POSIXct("2012-01-01"), as.POSIXct("2014-12-31"), by="day"),
             seq(as.POSIXct("2012-01-01"), as.POSIXct("2015-12-31"), by="day"))

obs <- list(sample(0:100,1096,replace=TRUE),
           sample(0:100,1461,replace=TRUE))

var <- list()
for (i in 1:10) {
   model[[i]] <- list()
   model[[i]][[1]] <- sample(0:100,1096,replace=TRUE)
   model[[i]][[2]] <- sample(0:100,1461,replace=TRUE)
   for (j in 1:2) {
      rmseS=rmse(model[[i]][[j]],obs[[j]],na.rm=TRUE)
      rbind(df,rmseS) -> df
    }
}
```

With the above code, I can calculate the total RMSE, but what I would like is to calculate yearly RMSE as well. I understand that`ggof` in the `hydroGOF` package can calculate yearly, monthly etc stats, but I would have to reformat my data drastically. Is there a way I can use the `dateO` list to calculate yearly RMSE, with the added complication that each site has a different number of years? I want to be able to write my data in a data frame, which is why I `rbind`, in my code, with site names and model names and ideally, with years such that the results will be readable like this:

```
RMSE  Site   Model    Year
0.4   Site1  Model1   2012
0.3   Site1  Model1   2013
0.4   Site1  Model2   2012
```

and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did manage to do what I wanted to do but with a slightly different method than asked above (I just went with what worked...). I've had to write all the data in a data frame and then calculate the rmse outside of the loops, as such:

```
for (i in 1:10) { # Loop over models

   model[[i]] <- list()
   model[[i]][[1]] <- sample(0:100,1096,replace=TRUE)
   model[[i]][[2]] <- sample(0:100,1461,replace=TRUE)
   for (j in 1:2) { # Loop over sites
       year=as.numeric(format(dateO[[j]][length(dateO[[j]])],"%Y"))
       # Loop over days.
       for (k in 1:length(dateO[[j]])){
       # Create a data frame with the vars needed to calculate yearly RMSE.
       df <- rbind(df,data.frame(as.character(i),as.character(j),
                                  model[[i]][[j]][[k]],obs[[j]][[k]],year))
       }
   }
}
colnames(df) <- c("Model_number","Site_number","Model_value","Obs_value","Year")
newdf <- df %>% group_by(Year,Site_number,Model_number) %>% summarise(RMSE=rmse(Model_value,Obs_value,na.rm=TRUE))
```